# Is there a dedicated Language Class in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style, locale, code-cleanup

While refactoring one of my projects, i replaced all language ISO Codes like `"en"` and `"de"` Strings with the `Locale` Class and its constants `Locale.ENGLISH` and `Locale.GERMAN` to make it more refactor save and to minimize error sources. I use then locale.getLanguage() to get the ISO Code as String.

The problem that i have with this approach is the **overhead of the Locale Class** in form of the country and variant fields. I am considering **writing my own Language Class** to avoid this overhead.

Is it good practice to use a custom class, or is there already a dedicated `Language` Class that i missed?

Comment: The overhead should only be the first time you create a Locale. If you cache these locales, the overhead should be trivial. Are you talking about some other sort of overhead?

Comment: How does this overhead affect you? What is the problem?

Comment: do you think that English from UK is the same language as English from the US?? or Spanish from Spain is the same than the one from Mexico?? Yeah one can understand each other but from the point of view of a computer they are different (different meanings for the same word, different spellings for the same meaning, etc)

Comment: I did not mean overhead in means of resources but that i am not using the right tool to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed one of the basic priciples of programming: Don't reinvent the wheel.

Yes, the `Locale` class can do more than you need, but the overhead is usually extremely negligible. Also, using it enables other coders to instantly understand that part of your code.

Comment: +1 for the note, that Locale will be instantly understood for others

Answer (score 2):

The overhead is not that high. This gets every Locale.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales())
    l.toString();
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println(time + " ms.");
```

prints

```
15 ms.
```